# How to use a Table type in query

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 9000 row in `News` table and use this code for selecting 20 from it:

```
Select *
From (
      Select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateSend DESC) AS Num
      From News
      Where SubjectID in(Select MenuSubject.SubjectID
                         From MenuSubject inner join Menu on MenuSubject.MenuID = Menu.MenuID)
) as myTable
where myTable.Num BETWEEN 100 and 120
```

But time is 28 second spent reading! Also, I test this query with out join table and get result at 1 second.

So, I want use `Table` type for select join table and use this in query. I made new `Table` type using the following code:

```
DECLARE @MyTable2 IntListTable
Insert Into @MyTable2
Select MenuSubject.SubjectID
From MenuSubject inner join Menu on MenuSubject.MenuID = Menu.MenuID
Select *
From (
      Select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateSend DESC) AS Num
      From News
      Where SubjectID in @MyTable2
) as myTable
where myTable.Num BETWEEN 100 and 120
```

But get Error in

> SubjectID in @MyTable2

Error:

Incorrect syntax near '@MyTable2'.

---

Edit:

I test my code with:

```
Select myTable.Title
```

or use this code instead join table:

```
Where SubjectID in(13,14,20,21,25,24,26,24,28,29,30,54,55,60,47,98,99,65,14,20,33,666,987,254)
```

get result at 1 second.

but use this code in query:

```
Select myTable.MoreText
```

time is 28 second spent reading!. why!?

Comment: I am guessing you need in (select SubjectID from @MyTable2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Select x.Num
From (

      Select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateSend DESC) AS Num
      From News
      Where SubjectID in(Select MenuSubject.SubjectID
                         From MenuSubject inner join Menu on MenuSubject.MenuID = Menu.MenuID)
)  x
where x.Num <21
```

Comment: I want select * from mytable no select x.Num, so i use X.*  time is 28 second spent reading

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH myTempTable as (Select MenuSubject.SubjectID
                         From MenuSubject inner join Menu on MenuSubject.MenuID = Menu.MenuID)
Select *
From (
      Select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateSend DESC) AS Num
      From News
      Where SubjectID in (SELECT SubjectID FROM myTempTable)
) as myTable
where myTable.Num BETWEEN 100 and 120
```

You can try above query.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no need for a User-Defined Table Type in this query. It adds work but no actual benefit.

The problem is most likely the fact that you are using an `IN` list as those translate out to be an `OR` condition for each of the values. But an `IN` list isn't needed either.

This query can actually be simplified by rethinking it in terms of an INNER JOIN, which should be better as it will allow the Query Optimizer to do its job.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT nw.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateSend DESC) AS [Num]
      FROM News nw
      INNER JOIN (
          MenuSubject
          INNER JOIN Menu
                  ON MenuSubject.MenuID = Menu.MenuID
      ) ON MenuSubject.SubjectID = nw.SubjectID
) AS myTable
WHERE myTable.Num BETWEEN 100 AND 120;
```

One final simplification that can be made, though I doubt it is needed here since 9000 rows is almost no data at all, is to first dump the results to a local temporary table and then use that in the `INNER JOIN`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #Subjects
(
  SubjectID INT NOT NULL -- PRIMARY KEY -- test with and without PK to see if it helps
);

INSERT INTO #Subjects (SubjectID)
  SELECT MenuSubject.SubjectID
  FROM   MenuSubject
  INNER JOIN Menu
          ON Menu.MenuID = MenuSubject.MenuID;

SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT nw.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateSend DESC) AS [Num]
      FROM News nw
      INNER JOIN #Subjects sub
              ON sub.SubjectID = nw.SubjectID
) AS myTable
WHERE myTable.Num BETWEEN 100 AND 120;
```